# What is the best way to optimise this code? Is batching viable here?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, batch-processing

The code below works, however it is extremely slow. Can someone explain to me how one could optimise it? I tried batching but it did not work.

```
#%% Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

#%% Loop
df_na = []
    for x, y in zip(df_cols['COLUMN_NAME'], df_cols['TABLE_NAME']):
        try:
            na_query = '''SELECT COUNT(*) AS ''' + str(x) +  ''' FROM [db].[schema].''' + str(y) + ''' WHERE ''' + str(x) + ''' IS NULL'''
            print(na_query)
            df_narecords = pd.read_sql_query(na_query, engine, index_col=str(x))
            df_narecords['Null Column Name'] = str(x)
            df_narecords['Table Name'] = str(y)
            df_na.append(df_narecords) 
        except:
            pass
    df_naFINAL = pd.concat(df_na)
    df_naFINAL.to_csv(r'filepath', mode='a', index=False)
```

Comment: Is df a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - yes it is

Comment: Could you add the relevant tags and imports to the question?

Comment: you mentioned that you tried batching but it did not work. It's essential to clarify why it didn't work, as batching is a common optimization technique for database queries. If you can provide more details about the issues you encountered with batching,

Comment: i think you want the opposite of batching, less batches and more selects per table

Comment: Note: if you `COUNT(column_name)` it will exclude nulls automatically making the WHERE clause redundant.

Answer (score 2):

If N is the number of tables and M is the number of columns per table, you're running N*M queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> WHERE <column> IS NULL
```

Instead, you can run N queries like this (untested, you didn't specify your RDBMS):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_column1_null,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_column2_null,
  ...
FROM <table>
```

Presumably, this should run much faster, since you'll be doing N full table scans instead of N*M ones (speedup of some queries by index usage notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was with batching and as usual it was a pesky parenthesis!

Code below:

```
#%% Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql
import time

#%% Get table names and check which tables have null values
df_na = []
batchsize= 100
for i in range(0,len(df_cols),batchsize):
    batch = df_cols[i:i+batchsize]
    for x, y in zip(batch['COLUMN_NAME'], batch['TABLE_NAME']):
        try:
            na_query = '''SELECT COUNT(*) AS ''' + str(x) +  ''' FROM [db].[schema].''' + str(y) + ''' WHERE ''' + str(x) + ''' IS NULL'''
            df_narecords = pd.read_sql_query(na_query, engine, index_col= str(x))
            df_narecords['Null Column Name'] = str(x)
            df_narecords['Table Name'] = str(y)
            df_na.append(df_narecords)
            print(df_na)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            pass
df_naFINAL = pd.concat(df_na)
df_naFINAL = df_naFINAL.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Null Count'})
df_naFINAL.to_csv(r"filepath",mode='a',index=False)
```